# Ошибка в Google Chrome с верской

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Всем привет!) Все уже привыкли к тому что в браузере от Goggle все отображается как по маслу. Но сегодня это мнение для меня изменилось. А теперь по делу.
Данная ошибка наблюдается **ТОЛЬКО** в Google Chrome.
В результате рендеринга сайта образуется какая то не нужная строчка, в самом начале кода, которая сдвигает все элементы на строчку вниз, эту строчку я обнаружил инструментом Инспектирования элемента. Мало того, весь код выглядет примерно так:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body style="">﻿
    <title>Мой сайт</title>
    <link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <div id="topPan">
```

То есть элементы стоят не в правильном порядке!
Но это еще не все, когда открываешь исходный код - оказывается что все правильно!!! Почему GooChr Воспринимает мой сайт не правильно?

P.S. Когда я вставил DOCTYPE все браузеры его увидели, за исключением того же Chrome

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/216642

Comment: и вообще, [title](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/title) разве не в header должен быть ?

Comment: @eicto Ответил на свой вопрос ниже...

Comment: все-же исправьте разметку, чтобы соответствовать спецификации.

Comment: @eicto ошибка вся и заключается в том что в результате рендеринга страницы <head> уходил не в то место! Но наверное это я так плохо изьясняюсь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я поменял кодировку с UTF-8 на UTF-8 **БЕЗ BOM** и все заработало!!! Исключительно магия!!!

Comment: погуглил, понял откуда в польских исходниках битые заголовки html

Answer (score 0):

Нужно сбросить стили. В самый верх Вашего css:

```
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
```

И что это за верстка такая кривая?